# OpenProcess returns NULL every time in c++?

Tags: c++, process, handle

I "copied" a simple code snippet from a site and adjusted it to a game I was trying to hack. An old game with no multiplayer, basically just to practice all this memory editing stuff. Every time my program successfully returns a window handle, but then fails to return the process handle. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    long address = 0x47C0F04;
    int newvalue = 200; 
    DWORD newvaluesize = sizeof(newvalue);

    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(0, L"No One Lives Forever");
    HANDLE pHandle; 
    DWORD pid; 

    if(hWnd != 0) { 
        cout << "Found windowx.\n"; 
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
        pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid); 
    } 
    else {
        cout << "Can't find window\n";
    } 
    if(pHandle !=0) { 
        WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)address, (LPVOID)newvalue, newvaluesize, 0);    
        cout << "Written to memory successfully\n";
    } 
    else { 
        cout << "Couldn't get handle.\n";
    } 
    CloseHandle(pHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

The game is from 2000 if I recall correctly (really awesome game by the way) so I'm assuming it doesn't have any advanced anti-hack shield, since I can also pretty much edit the value of that address in cheat engine and it works with no hassle.

EDIT: I'll just explain what exactly happens. It always prints "Found window" but then it directly prints "Couldn't get handle". I don't get any compiler errors (I'm compiling in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express)

Comment: Why not throw in a few GetLastError calls to get more details of whats going on for a start??

Comment: Is there any anti-malware software installed on your computer that could prevent intrusions into processes by an unsigned executable, which your program is?

Comment: @Desmond I had microsoft security essentials enabled, but even when I disabled it (disabled real time protection, and when that didn't work I just ended it with process managed) it still had the same effect.

Comment: Probably another blank shot, but do you run your program with administrator rights?

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out. That was so stupid, I used the GetLastError mathematician suggested, and it said "Acess Denied" so I figured it would have been the admin rights thing. Truly a rookie's mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You must run your program as administrator to get a handle with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS permissions, this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As **GuidedHacking** mentioned you need to run program as Admin ,Use this code to check whether your process is running as **Admin rights.**

```
BOOL IsElevatedProcess()
{
    BOOL is_elevated = FALSE;
    HANDLE token = NULL;
    if (GT_IsPrivateMethod(gt_private_method, FUNC_NAME, LINE_NO))
    {
        if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &token))
        {
            TOKEN_ELEVATION elevation;
            DWORD token_sz = sizeof(TOKEN_ELEVATION);
            if (GetTokenInformation(token, TokenElevation, &elevation, sizeof(elevation), &token_sz))
            {
                is_elevated = elevation.TokenIsElevated;
            }
        }
        if (token)
        {
            CloseHandle(token);
        }
    }
    return is_elevated;
}
```